# Node JS Socket.io: Is it possible to wait for reply from other side of connection after an emit()?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Is anyone familiar with ways to set up Socket.io to wait for a response from the other side of the connection, after emitting a message?

For example:
Client (A) emits an event to Server (B), and waits for an event emitted from Server (B) in response to this, before continuing.  If no response is received in X seconds, execute a timeout function or return a default value.

Usage case: similar to socketio-auth, where a client connects to the socket.io server and must authenticate by emitting an 'authenticate' event within X seconds, or gets disconnected.  However, I'm seeking a more general case where I can create a function like awaitReply() which will emit an event along with data, and wait for another event emitted by the remote server, and return the data included with that event.

I realize a HTTP request/response cycle may be a better way to accomplish this, but it seems it may be possible with Promises: do a setTimeout() and simply reject the promise if the timeout expires, and create an io.on() listener to resolve the promise when the awaited event fires locally.

One thing I'm not sure about: how to turn off the io.on() listener after the event fires.  Yes there's an io.off() function, but I don't want to erase all events associated with that event name - just the one created for that particular call.  And there may be multiple calls being awaited simultaneously for the same event - don't want to delete all the listeners when one of them executes.

Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: Why does Client A have to "await" a response from Server B? How is this different from natively having Client A emit a message and define socket.on for the server event it is waiting for?

Comment: Because it needs to happen synchronously within another function.  For example, to authenticate an action against a remote database - need to wait for the response before continuing with the process.

Comment: Trying to understand this better. What is the client? What exactly do you want to accomplish by waiting? Is the client an HTML page? You could have the client use a modal dialog to "freeze" the browser. Then your socket.on() could dismiss the modal dialog when it receives the message from the server.

Comment: The use case is this: Using Socketio-auth: two servers are communicating with each other.  Server 'A' has the user authorization database. When a user connects to SocketIO on Server 'B', Server B needs to authenticate the user with the database which resides on Server 'A' before firing the authentication function for the client connection.  Therefore it must wait for a reply.  I was hoping to use Promises and the 'await' directive to avoid a blocking call.

Comment: Did you consider having Server B access the database on Server A using a regular database connection (instead of Socket.IO)?

Comment: That's probably a better option. I was just wondering if it could be done with socket.io.

Answer (score 0):

you will be performing a synchronous long pull, and defeat the purpose of socket.io